# htaccess 301 redirect, how to do it properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect my old website as directory of my new website.

olddomain.tld = newdomain.tld/directory/

Redirect 301 / https://newdomain.tld/directory/

But when i set
Redirect 301 /contactus/ https://newdomain.tld/contact-us/
result is https://newdomain.tld/directory/contact-us/ 404, because of wrong path.

How can resolve this issue?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you avoid `Redirect` and use more powerful `mod_rewrite` engine.

You may use these rules on your old host's .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^contactus/(.*)$ https://newdomain.tld/contact-us/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.tld/directory/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache.

**References:**

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [.htaccess tips and tricks](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php)